# Why does "dotnet ef migrations add" start my application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I've created a new project using .NET 6 and EF Core 6 but when I try to create a migration using `dotnet ef migrations add`, the CLI begins running the application after "Build succeeded.".

This isn't preventing the migrations from being created but adds a considerable amount of time to the process as I need to wait for the application to exit before issuing any other commands.

Snippet of dotnet ef migrations add output:

[image: snippet of dotnet ef migrations add output]

Within the same solution I have many other projects using .NET 5 and EF Core 5 which all create migrations as expected (just builds the project, doesn't run it).

Is this new functionality for EF Core 6 or is there a configuration somewhere which would cause this behaviour?

**EDIT**

It seems like the issue is EF Core ignoring implimentations of IDesignTimeDbContext factory during migration creation and instead defaults to obtaining an instance of the DbContext from the host builder. Apparently can also happen with EF Core 5.

There is an open issue on the dotnet/efcore github here: [Migrations script not using IDesignTimeDbContextFactory](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25053)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm using EF Core 6, I'll update the question

Comment: Are you using the [minimal API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in the NET6 project?

Comment: @IvanStoev No, I'm using full controllers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also met this problem. I use ASP.Net Core 6 WebApi with full controllers.

I saw [march's comment on a GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25053#issuecomment-1108972550) ([Migrations script not using IDesignTimeDbContextFactory](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25053)), which gave me inspiration.

So, I changed `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)`(obsolete in .NET6) to `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` in Program.cs and now the problem is solved. Unfortunately, I still don't know the specific causes of the problem.

"dotnet ef migrations add" will still start application but Host will throw a `StopTheHostException` to stop the ASP.NET Core Host and then will create migration related files successfully which likes

```sh
Build started...
Build succeeded.
[16:46:18 INF] Configuring web host (Identity.API)...
[16:46:18 FTL] Program terminated unexpectedly (Identity.API)!
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver+HostingListener+StopTheHostException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver+HostingListener+StopTheHostException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver.HostingListener.OnNext(KeyValuePair`2 value)
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.Write(String name, Object value)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at Program.<<Main>$>g__CreateHostBuilder|0_0(IConfiguration configuration, String[] args) in G:\ASPNETCore\HongJieSun.Innermost\Services\Innermost.Identity\Innermost.Identity.API\Program.cs:line 47
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in G:\ASPNETCore\HongJieSun.Innermost\Services\Innermost.Identity\Innermost.Identity.API\Program.cs:line 11
To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.
```

Comment: Following your suggestion I migrated from `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` to `WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)` and am seeing the same result. Still a bit strange but much better than before as Polly retries were wasting a lot of time. Thanks!

Comment: Exception is annoying, but this solution is working, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Starting with EF Core 7.0, you can execute code based on flag `EF.IsDesignTime`

Flag will be set to true when the application is being executed by an EF design-time tool like `dotnet ef migrations add`.

You can find more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.isdesigntime?view=efcore-7.0) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#detect-when-tools-are-running).

Comment: This answer would be more helpful is you added what to do with EF.ISDesignTime to prevent a build from occurring and allowing the migration Add to work

Comment: @ickydime This is just a flag indicating if you are adding migrations.
It only depends on you which part of code you don't want to run then. I believe you should run everything by default, and only exclude specific part of code, like querying external services etc. There is no generic answer to that.

Comment: To add, if you're bothered by the tool throwing The entry point exited without ever building an IHost, you can do this: if (EF.IsDesignTime) { new HostBuilder().Build().Run(); return; } at the start of Program.cs, obviously skipping all your other initialization code and just returning an empty host.