# Why does application start with dotnet ef migrations add?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-6.0

I have strange behavior with EF Core tools in developer PowerShell in VS2019.

After creating migration with this command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add VisibleLink -p .\src\Only.Portal.Data\ -s .\src\Only.Portal.Web
```

And it is causing to start my app, but previously it didn't. The method to apply last migrations, which causes `dotnet ef migrations remove` fully broken, because when using it, it firstly starts an app and then calls `Migrate().

Then I am getting a message:

> The migration '20220128090939_VisibleLink' has already been applied to the database. Revert it and try again. If the migration has been applied to other databases, consider reverting its changes using a new migration instead

Looks like dead end loop.

Comment: is the real problem 'starts the app' or 'migration already applied'?

Comment: Real problem that it is starting the app and inside app calling Migrate() method, causing dotnet ef migrations remove push error saying migration already applied.

Comment: when you say 'starting the app', do you mean the app ui/process has been launched?

Comment: Only API. -> Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\Users\hoozr\source\repos\portal-web\src\Only.Portal.Web
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not satisfied with author's own answer <s>marked as accepted solution</s>. It's very unclear to me what the actual "solution" is here. It is only mentioned that one should "use Startup". No mention of the exact thing that actually resolves the issue.

I'm running a .NET 6 ASP.NET app with minimal API for startup, and ran into the same issue. `dotnet ef migrations` would call my startup code, causing the entire application to try to start up, and fail (specifically I had a service that ran directly at start, that tried to use a database table that I'm actively trying to create a migration for).

I solved it by stepping away from the minimal API and creating a `Program` class, with a "fake" `public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder` method.

```cs
public class Program
{
    // Have a Main that actually runs/starts your app with all the logic
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Here I do automatic migrations...
        // ...

        // Web app initialization logic
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

        var app = builder.Build();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app
            .MapControllers()
            .RequireAuthorization();
        // etc.

        await app.RunAsync();
    }
    
    // Have a CreateHostBuilder that simply returns a default builder.
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing Entity Framework migrations stuff, not starting full application");
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();
    }
}
```

EF will look for a `CreateHostBuilder` method in `Program`. If it finds it, it won't call `Main`, and basically skip the entire initialization of your webapp and return a very empty host builder, sufficient enough for EF to do its work.

This feels like a bit of a hack, and it might not work at a later date.

### Better solution for EF Core 7.0+ users

If you're using EF Core 7.0 or higer, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76127936/439094). You can now return an empty host builder when [EF.IsDesignTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.isdesigntime?view=efcore-7.0) is `true`:

```cs
// Program.cs

if (EF.IsDesignTime) {
    new HostBuilder().Build().Run();
    return;
}

// Normal startup
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseAuthentication();
// ...
```

Comment: This is awesome. Especially the 7.0 solution!

Answer (score 0):

According to `@frogerdevs` help. Need to implement:

> Use Startup with the new minimal hosting mode

From Microsoft article of migrating to the .NET 6.0:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score -1):

Basically it is telling you that the migration you are trying to remove is applied to your local database already, so it won't remove it, you need to run

`dotnet ef database update previous-migration-id`

then you can run

`dotnet ef migration remove`

Comment: Hey, that is not valid answer. I have already used dotnet ef database update command previous-migration. And after it successful execute, I execute dotnet ef migration remove. And my app somehow starting in console and somewhere inside calling Migrate() to apply that migration what I want to remove and after that it saying  that it has already been applied to the database.